# Run ElasticSearch in Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to use ElasticSearch plugin (https://github.com/cgoIT/gradle-elasticsearch-plugin) in Gradle Kotlin DSL, but it doesn't seem to work.
The plugin works perfectly in Gradle DSL.

build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    application
    id("cgoit.gradle.elasticsearch").version("0.2.3.1")
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.2")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre")
}

application {
    mainClass.set("com.example.App")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    doFirst {
        startElasticsearch { }
    }

    doLast {
        stopElasticsearch {}
    }
}
```

There is no any error in logs, but elasticsearch was not started:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date
12:32:20: Task execution finished 'test'.
```

Sample project: https://github.com/baczus/gradle-kotlin-dsl-elasticsearch

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There is no error. Plugin just doesn't start.

Comment: Please look at elastic logs and see if you find anything useful to share

Comment: Problem is that Elastic doesn't start. It looks like Gradle not execute the plugin at all.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're using linux or something. Maybe looking at the elastic service logs will help you. You can check `sudo service elasticsearch status` or even look deeper at the log folder (it's usually in `/var/log/elasticsearch/`) You might find some answers about why it stopped.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Linux, but Elastic itself is not a problem, because the logic to run Elastic instance is not executed by Gradle. I think the problem is related with Kotlin DSL abstraction. Configuration using Gradle DSL works without any issues.